# how to make part of the job to execute only once in quartz scheduler in java,i.e, consumer of the kafka

Tags: java, servlets, apache-kafka, quartz-scheduler, kafka-consumer-api

I am using java servlet. In the web.xml file I have initialized the quartz scheduler. I have 2 separate jobs and two triggers. I am using quartz.properties file which is in resource folder. Below is my web.xml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
     <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>quartz:start-on-load</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param> 

 <listener>
<listener-class>
org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.hpe.statistics.StatisticsQuartzListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>StatisticsIvr</servlet-name>
<display-name>StatisticsIvr</display-name>
<description></description>
<servlet-class>StatisticsIvr</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>StatisticsIvr</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/StatisticsIvr</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

StatisticsIvr is my servlet name. StatisticsQuartzListener is the class where I initialized all jobs and triggers. com.hpe.statistics. is the package name where I have StatisticsQuartzListener class.
Below is StatisticsQuartzListener class which implements ServletContextListener.

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent ctx)
{

    JobDetail newfilejob = JobBuilder.newJob(NewFileJob.class)
            .withIdentity("fileJob", "group1").build();

    JobDetail newlinejob = JobBuilder.newJob(NewFileJob.class)
            .withIdentity("lineJob", "group2").build();

    Trigger filetrigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("fileTrigger", "group1")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                            .withIntervalInMinutes(6).repeatForever())
            .build();
    Trigger linetrigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("lineTrigger", "group2")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                            .withIntervalInMinutes(2).repeatForever())
            .build();

    try {
            scheduler1 = ((StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getServletContext()
                    .getAttribute(
                            QuartzInitializerListener.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY))
                    .getScheduler();
            scheduler1.scheduleJob(newfilejob, filetrigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {

        }

     try {
            scheduler2 = ((StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getServletContext()
                    .getAttribute(
                            QuartzInitializerListener.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY))
                    .getScheduler();
            scheduler2.scheduleJob(newlinejob, linetrigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {

        }

}
```

below is quartz.properties file

```
# Main Quartz configuration
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = StatisticsQuartzListener
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
```

In newlinejob (2nd job) I want to execute part of the code only once. The NewLineJob class is as below

```
public class NewLineJob implements Job{



public static final String KAFKAHOST="kafkahost";
public static final String KAFKAPORT="kafkaport";
public static final String KAFKATOPICNAME="topicname";
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
 HashMap<String,Long> consumerMap=new HashMap<String,Long>();
 File lastModifiedFile;



 String flag="off";



public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException
        {

            String kafkahost=dataMap.getString(KAFKAHOST);
            String kafkaport=dataMap.getString(KAFKAPORT);
            String topicname=dataMap.getString(KAFKATOPICNAME);


              SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
              Date d = new Date();
              String timeStamp = sf.format(d);

              int i=0;
              String writeString;
              if(flag.equals("off"))
              {
                  flag="on";
              Properties propsConsumer = new Properties();


                propsConsumer.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkahost+":"+kafkaport);
                propsConsumer.put("group.id", "test");
                propsConsumer.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
                propsConsumer.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
                propsConsumer.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
                propsConsumer.put("key.deserializer", 
                     "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
                propsConsumer.put("value.deserializer", 
                     "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");         
                consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(propsConsumer);

                  //Kafka Consumer subscribes list of topics here.
                consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicname)); 

              }

              ///some other operations which I want according to sceduler
        }
```

The part which I want execute only once is

```
Properties propsConsumer = new Properties();


                propsConsumer.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkahost+":"+kafkaport);
                propsConsumer.put("group.id", "test");
                propsConsumer.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
                propsConsumer.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
                propsConsumer.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
                propsConsumer.put("key.deserializer", 
                     "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
                propsConsumer.put("value.deserializer", 
                     "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");         
                consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(propsConsumer);

                  //Kafka Consumer subscribes list of topics here.
                consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicname));
```

Because I dont want to create a new consumer for every time when scheduler triggers. I just want to use the same kafka consumer in the rest of the code everytime when the scheduler triggers.
Even I tried to put the part of the code which I wanted only once in the constructor. But it gets an error as key.deserializer has no default value.
What modification I have to do ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you not try running this code outside of Quartz?

Comment: Yes I tried. But I need the same  kafka consumer in the rest of scheduler program. If I write this part of the code outside quartz I cant get that kafka consumer in scheduler job.

Comment: My point is that `key.deserializer has no default value` is not a scheduler issue

Comment: Is there any way to write this part of the code outside the job and can access that kafka consumer in the scheduler job?

Comment: yes. key.deserializer is kafka consumer issue

Comment: I only have experience with Oozie, and I almost always write the code, run it first to test it, then make Oozie run a JAR file